# Check to see if the first letter of email matches 's'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to validate that the first letter in all email starts with an 's' if not fix it. This is the script the 2 case statement is not working! Is their a better way I can see if the first letter in the email address is correct.
If the email beginning letter is 's' its a match,
else if the beginning letter is not an 's' mismatch

```
Select
    p.personID,
    p.studentNumber,
    c.email,
    SUBSTRING(c.email, 2, CHARINDEX('@',c.email) - 2) StudentNumberFromEmail,
    substring(c.email,1, 1) SfromEmail,
    -- find missing email and check to see if studentNumber in email is correct
    case when p.studentNumber <>  SUBSTRING(c.email, 2, CHARINDEX('@',c.email) - 2)
        then 'mismatched'
      when SUBSTRING(c.email, 2, CHARINDEX('@',c.email)-2) is null
        then 'email missing'
      else 'matched' end, 
            -- does the email start with 's'
    CONCAT('s',p.studentNumber,'@myemail.org') 'email fixed',
    case when c.email <>  SUBSTRING(c.email, 1, 1)
        then 'mismatched'
      when SUBSTRING(c.email, 1,1) is null
        then 'email missing'
      else 'matched' end
    from Person p
    join Enrollment e on e.personID = p.personID
        and e.endDate is Null and e.serviceType = 'P' 
    join calendar cal on cal.calendarID = e.calendarID 
    join SchoolYear sy on sy.endYear = e.endYear and sy.active = 1
    join Contact c on c.personID = p.personID
```

Comment: I figured it out I took out the second case statement and added to the where clause or Substring(ct.email,1,1) <> 's'

Comment: Whitespace is free you know

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I took out the second case statement and added to the where clause or Substring(ct.email,1,1) <> 's'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).